# small amplitude oscillation of rotating system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, approximation

I've solved the euler-lagrange equation for a frictionless bead on circular vertical loop of radius a where the loop is rotating at $\Omega$ to get the equation of motion for the bead as $$\frac{d^{2}\theta}{dt^2} = \sin\theta ( \Omega^{2}\cos\theta-\frac{g}{a})$$ when I look at my free body diagram the system is obviously stable about $\theta = 0$ but when I use small angle approximations used the conditions that $\Omega^{2}>\frac{g}{a}$ I get $$\frac{d^{2}\theta}{dt^2} = \Omega^{2}\theta$$ this is an exponential decay and not oscillatory and my problem sheet asks me to find the period and so I've evidently made a mistake in my approximations as my equation of motion is in agreement with the answers given.

Comment: in lowest order u get  for the rhs $(\Omega^2-g/a)\theta$ which is always positive so ur conclusion still holds. maybe u are missing a minus sign somewhere?

Comment: That's what I thought. It's an optional extra at the end so it may just be that it is exponential and they want us to think about why it's the case

Comment: if u could write down the full lagrangian i might can help u

Comment: It think the oint is that we have two fixpoints: one at $0$ and one at $\pi$ and one of them will be unstable, so the small angle approximation isn't good and we get the above ''solution''

Comment: $\theta = 0$ is not the stable point for $\Omega^2a > g$. For high $\Omega$, the stable point is defined by $\cos \theta_0 = \frac{g}{\Omega^2 a}$. You would need to find the oscillation frequency around such a $\theta_0$.

Comment: so we want the expansion around $\pi/2$? so $\theta'' = \Omega^2(- \theta + \pi/2 -g/a\Omega^2)$ in which case our frequency is just $\Omega$?

Comment: @goods Check the answer I have posted.

Comment: Try to read through this http://www.physics.iitm.ac.in/~arul/PH1010/AJP000506JacobiEllipticBead.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\theta = \theta_0 + \psi$. Then the equation of motion beocomes $$\frac{d^{2}(\theta_0 + \psi)}{dt^2} = \sin(\theta_0+\psi) \left( \Omega^{2}\cos(\theta_0+\psi)-\frac{g}{a}\right).$$ For small $\psi$ this is easily seen to be same as $$\frac{d^{2} \psi}{dt^2} =-\Omega^{2} \sin^2\theta_0 \psi$$ after using $\cos \theta_0=\frac{g}{\Omega^2a}$ and expanding the cosine. Therefore the oscillation freq is $\Omega \sin\theta_0.$